# clear both for table height?

Tags: css, email

my border of table isn't working in email template, take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/7MzfR/2/

```
<table style="border: 1px solid #9cbdcc;" border="1">
```

the problem is the height, use clear like div?

Answer (score 1):

Not working because you insert a table inside another table without `tr` and `td`.

try this:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid #9cbdcc;" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>

....
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7MzfR/4/)